# react context rerenders every child of Provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-context

```
    import React, { useReducer, useEffect ,Component} from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    const AppContext = React.createContext();

import React from "react";

const withRandomColors = WrappedComponent => {
  return class RandomColors extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.randomColors = [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
        "cyan",
        "lavender",
        "skyblue",
        "orange",
        "pink",
        "yellow"
      ];
    }

    getRandomColors() {
      const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % 9;
      return this.randomColors[num];
    }

    render() {
       console.log("Rerendering wrapper Component");
      return <WrappedComponent randomColor={this.getRandomColors()} />;
    }
  };
};

class Number extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    console.log("rendering Number Component");
    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {({ number }) => {
          return (
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: `${this.props.randomColor}` }}>
              {number} <br />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

class Text extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
     console.log("rendering Text Component");
    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {({ text }) => (
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: `${this.props.randomColor}` }}>
            {text} <br />
          </div>
        )}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedText=withRandomColors(Text);
const WrappedNumber=withRandomColors(Number);

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      number: Math.random() * 100,
      text: "testing context api"
    };
  }

  updateNumber = () => {
    const randomNumber = Math.random() * 100;
    this.setState({ number: randomNumber });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("rendering app")
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <div>
          <h1>Welcome to React</h1>
          <WrappedNumber  />
          <WrappedText />
          <button onClick={this.updateNumber}>Change Number </button>
        </div>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  mountNode
);
```

when clicked on ChangeNumber button console displays

```
rendering app

Rerendering wrapper Component

Rerendering Number Component

Rerendering wrapper Component

Rerendering Text Component
```

and background color changes for both number and text.

React context is supposed to rerender only consumers for the provider right? why is it rerendering All the children of Provider?

I expected  that only number changes keeping background color of Number and Text as same and below output from console once clicked on Change Number button since only consumers are supposed to rerender not the Text and Number components.

```
rendering app
```

what am I missing?

I took the code from [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l2kx18n35z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WrappedNumber` and `WrappedText` re-render when you update a state in the App component because in the Virtual DOM they come in the same hierarchy as the Provider and when the parent component updates the child components are updated too.

To avoid them from re-rendering you could provide them as children of App like

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      number: Math.random() * 100,
      text: "testing context api"
    };
  }

  updateNumber = () => {
    const randomNumber = Math.random() * 100;
    this.setState({ number: randomNumber });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("rendering app")
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <div>
          <h1>Welcome to React</h1>
          {this.props.children}
          <button onClick={this.updateNumber}>Change Number </button>
        </div>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App >
      <WrappedNumber  />
      <WrappedText />
 </App>,
  mountNode
);
```

Comment: Ok.but instead of providing the WrappedText and WrappedNumber chidren at runtime while creating App node  I hardcoded them in App's render method,but both yield the same result right? is there any difference between the two as to how react handles this?

Comment: AS I said, the difference is in how they are handled with virtual DOM. When component re-renders due to either state or props change, any component that is re-rendered directly within its render method is re-rendered. Context changes however are propogated specially to consumers. When you move out the components to the parent of App and render them as children prop, they don't re-render when App re-renders due to state change